# Calculate the next start time based on initial start time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Consider the following object:

```
new TimeObject 
{
    StartTime = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0 , 0),
    DurationInMinutes = 20,
    RepeatFrequencyType = RepeatFrequencyType.Month
    //This would mean repeat every 1 month.
    RepeatFrequency = 1,
}
```

I need to write code that will show a message on screen on the 1st of January 2019 and then repeat each month at same time. Now this is displayed on a website so you could load the page halfway through the message having to show up. So to solve this I thought of a two step process. First is to find what the next start time is (And this could be in the past if the user loads while the message is shown) and then step 2 is to figure out if I should show the message or not or how long until I need to show it. Step 2 is easy to solve, but step one is the trouble some. As such here is my solution which works with unit tests I have setup.

Please note that I am here showing code only for step 1 and that is the part I need help with. I explained the full picture for you to better understand the problem.

```
private DateTime GetNextMonthStartDate()
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    //If this is the first time it is running then we just return the initial start time.
    if (currentDate < StartTime.AddMinutes(DurationInMinutes)) return StartTime;
    //If we happen to run this when there is 0 minutes left, then return next month'start time.
    if (currentDate == StartTime.AddMinutes(DurationInMinutes)) return StartTime.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency);

    var dayOfTheMonth = StartTime.Day;
    var previousDateOfTheMonth = currentDate.AddMinutes(-DurationInMinutes);
    //As not every month has same number of days, if we are on one which has less days then we just run it on the last day of that month.
    var lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month);
    if (dayOfTheMonth > lastDay) dayOfTheMonth = lastDay;

    //If on the same day
    if (currentDate.Day == dayOfTheMonth)
    {
        var nextStartDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, StartTime.Hour, StartTime.Minute, StartTime.Second);
        var endDate = nextStartDate.AddMinutes(DurationInMinutes);

        //If the event is still lasting or has not started  then return current date and start time else return next month start time.
        return currentDate < endDate ? nextStartDate : nextStartDate.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency);
    }

    //If the event is still running but it started in previous day, we return start date of that previous day.
    if (currentDate.Day != previousDateOfTheMonth.Day && previousDateOfTheMonth.Day == dayOfTheMonth)
    {
        return new DateTime(previousDateOfTheMonth.Year, previousDateOfTheMonth.Month, previousDateOfTheMonth.Day, StartTime.Hour, StartTime.Minute, StartTime.Second);
    }

    //Subtract next day of the month (based on the current year and month and start date) from the current date
    var nextDayOfTheMonthDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, StartTime.Day);
    var currentDateWithoutTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day);
    var daysUntilDayOfTheMonth = nextDayOfTheMonthDate.Subtract(currentDateWithoutTime).TotalDays;

    //If days is less than 0 it means it has passed, so we will recalculate from the next month.
    if (daysUntilDayOfTheMonth < 0)
    {
        daysUntilDayOfTheMonth = nextDayOfTheMonthDate.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency).Subtract(currentDateWithoutTime).TotalDays;
    }

    //Get the next day, month and year by adding days from current time. This will ensure things like switching into next year won't cause a problem.
    var nextDate = currentDate.AddDays(daysUntilDayOfTheMonth);

    //return date time with nextDate year, month and day with startDate time.
    return new DateTime(nextDate.Year, nextDate.Month, nextDate.Day, StartTime.Hour, StartTime.Minute, StartTime.Second);
}
```

As you can see it feels somewhat complicated and now I need to this for Year frequency, Day, Hour, etc... I am wondering if there is simpler logic to accomplish this or potentially code built in the framework I could use to figure this out?

Comment: It would be much simpler if `RepeatFrequencyType` was a `TimeSpan`. One example is something like: `var nextTime = StartTime; while(nextTime < DateTime.Now) nextTime += RepeatFrequency;`

Comment: just out of curiousity what would your desired result be if you were repeating on the 31st of the month every month, since only seven months have 31 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to add `RepeatFrequency` to `StartTime` until you've reached a `DateTime` value that is greater than the current date.

If this is the case, I think you can just use a loop where you increment the `nextTime` by `RepeatFrequency` until `nextTime > DateTime.UtcNow`.

First, I'm making an assumption that you have an `enum` something like the following:

```
enum RepeatFrequencyType
{
    Minutes,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Weeks,
    Months,
    Years,
    FirstWeekdayOfMonth
}
```

If so, I think this logic may solve the issue:

```
class TimeObject
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public int DurationInMinutes { get; set; }
    public RepeatFrequencyType RepeatFrequencyType { get; set; }
    public int RepeatFrequency { get; set; }

    public DateTime NextStartTime()
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Grab the StartTime and add the duration
        var nextTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(DurationInMinutes);

        // Continue to increment it until it's greater than the current time
        while (currentTime >= nextTime)
        {
            switch (RepeatFrequencyType)
            {
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Minutes:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddMinutes(RepeatFrequency);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Hours:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddHours(RepeatFrequency);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Days:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddDays(RepeatFrequency);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Weeks:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddDays(RepeatFrequency * 7);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Months:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.Years:
                    nextTime = nextTime.AddYears(RepeatFrequency);
                    break;
                case RepeatFrequencyType.FirstWeekdayOfMonth:
                    nextTime = GetNextFirstWeekdayOfMonth(nextTime.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown value for RepeatFrequency specified.");
            }
        }

        // Remove the added duration from the return value
        return nextTime.AddMinutes(-DurationInMinutes);
    }

    private DateTime GetNextFirstWeekdayOfMonth(DateTime date)
    {
        // Start at the first day of the month
        var firstWeekday = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

        // While the first day is not a weekday, add a day
        while (firstWeekday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
               firstWeekday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            firstWeekday.AddDays(1);
        }

        // If the specified date is greater than the first weekday,
        // return the first weekday of the next month.
        if (date > firstWeekday)
        {
            firstWeekday = GetNextFirstWeekdayOfMonth(date.AddMonths(1));
        }

        return firstWeekday;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach I think makes sense. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You add the duration to the original start date to get the end time. So as long as the current time is greater than the end time you keep incrementing the date by its frequency. The first time the current date is less then end date, you return that value.

The only part in your code that doesn't account is the `RepeatFrequency` which represents the increment number for that period, so if it is 2 and type is month then it would be every 2 months. So I think to fix this is I just replace `(1)` with `(RepeatFrequncy)

Comment: If you want you can also add Weekly in there, in my code im just going to increment by 7 days times the RepeatFrequency.

Comment: If the start date is somewhere like 10 or 20 years in the past and the frequency type is minute, there is a lot of looping to happen here. Is there a way to mitigate that? I thought of lazy loading but then still the first time is going to be long even if I save the value.

Comment: You could, especially if you save the last run time so that calculations could be done on that value rather than the start value. But as it is, with a one minute frequency and a start date of 20 years ago, the method execution time is less than 2/10th of a second on my machine. And for 200 years, it's under 2 seconds. Are you seeing some perf issue?

Comment: I may end up migrating this logic to the browser and have not tested run times there. My concern was more for older and slower pcs handling something like this.

Comment: I've been trying to modify your logic to include First Weekday of the Month and Last Weekday of the month. For example: First Thursday of the month. I can't quite seem to get on track. I've been trying to do it by adding 7 days, but I also have to somehow add 1 month * RepeatFrequency to respect recurrence setting. Do you have any suggestions? Currently I was only able to solve it by not using your loop and doing something closer to my old way.

Comment: Inside the switch: `var nextMonth = nextTime.AddMonths(RepeatFrequency).Month; while (nextTime.Month < nextMonth) { nextTime = nextTime.AddDays(7); }`

Comment: Write a method that gets the first day of a month from a specified date, and then call that method. I can update it with a sample.

Comment: I updated the sample code with a new `enum` value for `FirstWeekdayOfMonth` and a helper method to `GetNextFirstWeekdayOfMonth` from a given `DateTime` argument. Then added a `case` that increments `nextTime` to the first day of the next month.